# Way to determine whether executing in IDE or not?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ide, conditional-compilation

In `C#/VB` in `Visual Studio 2010`, is there way in the code to determine whether the program is currently running in the IDE or not?

```
eg. If ProgramRunningInIDE Then MessageBox.Show exc.Message
```

Comment: Or just look at the Related list on the right side of this page

Comment: I believe this is a good use for `#if DEBUG`.

Comment: @IAbstract, not so if you're running in release configuration.

Comment: @Morrison: once I followed the string of dupe questions I learned something new.

Answer (score 35):

You could check if the debugger is attached with:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached
```

This essentially does the same thing.

Comment: Does this return true if in the IDE but in release mode?

Comment: @SteveSmith technically it can return false even in debug mode, so long as a debugger is not attached. The debugger can be attached to release builds too, in which case this will return true.

Answer (score -1):

There is an [IsInDesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.isindesignmode.aspx) property you can use. In some circumstances it isn't accurate, though, so you additionally may want to check the [UsageMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.licensemanager.usagemode%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

```
public static bool IsRunningInIdeContext
{
    get {
        if (DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode)
            return true;
        return LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime;
    }
}
```

Comment: IsInDesignMode can be used by a control (in a library) to understand if it's hosted in the designer(visual studio) or in a running application, but it have nothing to do about detecting if the application have been launghed by the IDE or not. IsInDesignMode will return true only for a control that have been istantiated BY the IDE, not if the app is launched by the IDE

Comment: Then please clarify that in your question. This is pretty much what I understand by 'the program is currently running in the IDE'.

Comment: @fjdumont During design-time your program isn't actually running, is it?